# Make text appear like it is being typed like with a typewriter

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make text appear as if it is being typed one letter at a time with JavaScript and jQuery?

I tried hiding the content and then revealing one letter at a time with many `setTimeout()` calls, but that seems highly inefficient.

Anyone know of a better way to do this or a script or plugin that can simulate this effect?

I also would like a blinking cursor!

Comment: What is inefficient about setTimeout()?

Comment: https://github.com/chadselph/jquery-typewriter

Comment: You could progressively move an element that obscures the text to the right in increments.

Comment: Here's an nice, tiny plugin to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10872412/2287470

Comment: @PinnyM That there are so many of them. one per each character.

Comment: @Asad hmmm, interesting way to look at it. I might try that.

Comment: @IrfanMir: You would only use one setTimeout at a time - after rendering the first letter, it would call setTimeout again to async render the next one.

Comment: @PinnyM Ah, that is a much better way to go about it.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4074399/220060

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery Typewriter available here: https://github.com/chadselph/jquery-typewriter

Here is an example of how it works:

```
  $('.someselector').typewrite({
    'delay': 100, //time in ms between each letter
    'extra_char': '', //"cursor" character to append after each display
    'trim': true, // Trim the string to type (Default: false, does not trim)
    'callback': null // if exists, called after all effects have finished
});
```

Answer (score 3):

here is an example I made

```js
(function($){$.fn.typeWrite=function(s){
        var o={content:$(this).text(),delay:50,t:this,i:0};
        if(s){$.extend(o,s);}o.t.text('');
        var i=setInterval(function() {
            o.t.text(o.t.text()+o.content.charAt(o.i++));    
            if(o.i==o.content.length){clearInterval(i);}}
        ,o.delay);
      return o.t;  
    };})(jQuery);
    
    $('#test').typeWrite({content:'The stuff to type'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=test></div>
```

Comment: you can also set the delay $('#test').typeWrite({content:'The stuff to type', delay:500});

Comment: I didn't downvote, but i wonder where this plugin came from. It looks like minified code that was beautified, leading me to believe you copied it from somewhere and didn't give credit.

Comment: It might aswell be with variable names like o s t and i, no comments, and no spacing.

Comment: why would you make it bigger, its a function, once it written you just use it

Comment: maintainability. Why would you make it smaller? If you need it to be smaller you can always minify it later, leaving the original in an easily maintainable state.

Comment: I can maintain it just fine, why are we even having this conversation, let's stop

Comment: Thumbs up but you could have added `<div id=test></div>` in your example to show beginner how to test your code. The only thing about this is that it does not support html so if you put it in bold for example it will display `<strong>Bold</strong>` instead of putting the code in bold